# enum C, global variable error: variable has initializer but incomplete type

Tags: c, enums, global-variables, typedef, extern

I used enum to have boolean variables in C using following code in header file:

```
enum myBool { FALSE = 0, TRUE = 1}; typedef enum _myBool Bool;
```

then I defined some global Bool variables with: `extern Bool low;`

then when I tried to initialize the variables to false in another `.c` file with `Bool low = FALSE` I get the error variable 'low' has initializer but incomplete type.

How can I fix this? Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your enum as `myBool` not `_myBool` so you need to change

```
typedef enum _myBool Bool;
```

to

```
typedef enum myBool Bool;
```

Answer (score 0):

> then I defined some global Bool variables with: `extern Bool low`;

so you have declared it in the another file. otherwise you will get linker error